# PySpark loop in groupBy aggregate function

Tags: pyspark, group-by, aggregate

I have a big table for which I m trying to calculate sums (with conditions) of some columns grouping by a location.

My code looks like this, and I have more and more columns

```
df.groupBy(location_column).agg(
        F.sum(F.when(F.col(col1) == True, F.col(value))).alias("SUM " + col1),
        F.sum(F.when(F.col(col2) == True, F.col(value))).alias("SUM " + col2),
        F.sum(F.when(F.col(col3) == True, F.col(value))).alias("SUM " + col3),
        ....
        # Additional lines for additional columns (around 20)
)
```

I want to refactor my code to look like less dumb, by basically doing something like

```
cols = [col1, col2, col3, ... , coln]
df.groupBy(location_column).agg([F.sum(F.when(F.col(x) == True, F.col(value))).alias("SUM " + x)] for x in cols)
```

It's not working because the agg() function does not take lists :

```
assert all(isinstance(c, Column) for c in exprs), "all exprs should be Column"
```

Is there a solution to refactor it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`for x in cols` should be inside the square brackets. You also need to put a `*` before the list comprehension to expand the arguments:

```
df.groupBy(location_column).agg(
    *[F.sum(F.when(F.col(x) == True, F.col(value))).alias("SUM " + x) for x in cols]
)
```